# how to find a class in JSON

Tags: .net, json

```
tabGTD {
    Class: Stream class
    Type: Receipt type
    Date :Current date

    PLUs [] {
        {
            No: PLU number
        }
    }
}
```

this is a sample json script. am using system.net.json reference..... and i have to find "tabGTD" and class,type  from json.( i can find it as field and value.) help me to find header class and each field.

Answer (score 0):

Python has pretty decent JSON handling interface included.
http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

I'd imagine json like this:

> tabGTD= '{ "Class": "Stream class",
>   "Type": "Receipt type", "Date":
>   "Current date", "PLUs": {"No": "PLU
>   number"} }'

Then you can get it loaded in python like this way:

```
>>> tabGTD= '{"Class": "Stream class","Type": "Receipt type","Date": "Current da
te","PLUs":{"No": "PLU number"}}'
>>> a=json.loads(tabGTD)
>>> a
{'Date': 'Current date', 'PLUs': {'No': 'PLU number'}, 'Type': 'Receipt type', '
Class': 'Stream class'}
>>> a['Class']
'Stream class'
>>> [a['Class'],a['Type']]
['Stream class', 'Receipt type']
```

**EDIT**
So you need to have tabGTD key in your json data:

```
>>> someJson= '{"tabGTD":{"Class": "Stream class","Type": "Receipt type","Date":
 "Current date","PLUs":{"No": "PLU number"}}}'
>>> someJson
'{"tabGTD":{"Class": "Stream class","Type": "Receipt type","Date": "Current date
","PLUs":{"No": "PLU number"}}}'
>>> a=json.loads(someJson)
>>> a
{'tabGTD': {'Date': 'Current date', 'PLUs': {'No': 'PLU number'}, 'Type': 'Recei
pt type', 'Class': 'Stream class'}}
>>> a.keys()
['tabGTD']
>>> 'tabGTD' in a.keys()
True

>>> if 'tabGTD' in a.keys():
...     tGTD=a['tabGTD'];
...
>>> tGTD
{'Date': 'Current date', 'PLUs': {'No': 'PLU number'}, 'Type': 'Receipt type', '
Class': 'Stream class'}
>>> tGTD['Type']
'Receipt type'
>>>
```

You can find some information on JSON format here: [json desc](http://www.json.org/)