# how to find field in JSON

Tags: json

```
// JSON
{
"items": [
  {
    "title": "welcoem home",
    "author": "Charles Dickens"
  },
  {
    "title": "Harry Potter",
    "author": "J rowling"
  }]
}
```

this is my json script..  i need to find "items" and title and author field and its value from this. am using reference system.net.json.

Comment: Did you revise your question before posting? Are you sure you can understand your own question? Please, edit your question and explain what you need... An d don't forget to tell us what language you are using.

Comment: it looks like you catch some json wave) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259098/how-to-find-a-class-in-json (less than 1 hour difference between questions)

Comment: i cant find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

In python?

```
data = """
{ "items": [ { "title": "welcoem home", "author": "Charles Dickens" }, { "title": "Harry Potter", "author": "J rowling" }] }
"""

import json
data2 = json.loads(data)
authors = [x['author'] for x in data2['items']]
```

Comment: i need code for dotnet . and i need to find "items" first. if ("items") then only find fileds ans values in it.